# How to make a tree leaf a solid color depending on how much light hits it (eevee)

Tags: node-editor

Is it possible to make each leaf of the tree a solid color from the colorramp depending on how much light is hitting it?

I've done a data transfer on it to copy the normals from a sphere to give it a more anime look but it'd look closer to the reference if each leaf didnt have cel shading on it and it was just a solid color as if you were using a paint brush and just doing little dots for leaves lol

(also dont mind the different color ramps i was just playing around ^-^")
[image: geometry from itsuryuu]
[image: geometry from itsuryuu]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea - one thing you could try is to disable shadows for whatever light source you're using - let the toon shader handle the "shadow" effects. That way the leaves change their shade based on how shaded they are from the light source, but don't receive shadows from other leaves which would cause their subsequent leaf colors to become non-uniform:

[image: ToonShadow1]

The material I used is almost exactly the same as yours, for reference:

[image: ToonShadow2]